# Unknown compilation error with generics in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, eclipse-indigo

The following compilation error makes no sense to me, and I was hoping someone would be able to elucidate:

```
static public void main(String args[]) throws ZipException, IOException
{
    File file = new File("C:\\temp");
    ZipFile zip_file = new ZipFile(file);
    Enumeration<ZipEntry> entries = zip_file.entries();
}
```

I get the following error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Enumeration<capture#1-of ? extends ZipEntry> to Enumeration<ZipEntry>`

In order to get the above code to compile, I had to replace the `entries` declaration to use the generics `<? extends ZipEntry>`. Why do I have to do this? Doesn't ZipEntry extend ZipEntry? (Isn't that vacuously true?) Why does the compiler complain about that?

If it helps, I'm using Java 7.03 with Eclipse Indigo 64 bit.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I forgot to post the error code! Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ZipFile.entries()` returns an enumeration of extended `ZipEntry` types but is not confined to `ZipEntry` itself so you need to use:

```
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zip_file.entries();
```

This allows for other types such as `JarEntry` objects to be used in `ZipEntry` Enumerations.

Comment: JarEntry extends ZipEntry, so the following code would be legal: `ZipEntry zip = new JarEntry()`.  This is contravariance, which is legal in java.  The OP is asking why you can not use Enumeration<? extends ZipFile> to set a Enumeration<ZipFile> variable... which by the logic of contravariance should be legal.

Comment: Covariance works normally for objects but not when they are used in generics.

Answer (score 2):

**If you look closely(source code)**, it return `Enumeration<ZipEntry>` only as below:

```
     return new Enumeration<ZipEntry>() {
            private int i = 0;
            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            .....
            .....
```

But return type is declared as `public Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries() {` to **relax the restriction** on the return type. If you wish to override `entries()` method through your custom subclass of `Zipfile`,  you may want to use **one of the subclasses of the `ZipEntry`** as return type from the same method i.e. `ZipEntry`

If you don't want to use generics, you may want to write as :

```
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  Enumeration entries = zip_file.entries();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Make sure that the file exists and is accessible, you can also try this 

Enumeration<ZipEntry> entries = (Enumeration<ZipEntry>) zip_file.entries();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<Z extends ZipEntry>` and replace all of the `?` instances in you methods if you have any, with `Z`. You are not limited to `Z`, you can use any letter you like.